# Excluding results of a specific content type using KQL

Tags: search, search-results

I'm using a search results web part connected to a search box and I'd like to get everything within the site except items of a specific content type. My query originally looked like this:

```
{searchTerms} Path:{Site}
```

I can get only matching results from a list with the content type like this

```
{searchTerms} Path:{Site} ContentType:My Content Type Name
```

I've tried multiple combinations such as putting a - before ContentType, adding NOT before ContentType, and adding AND NOT but there are very few values returned each time (I'm sure this should not be the case). Is there a way to get everything except these types of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If yo want to remove a specific content type use either the exact name in a equals query (note the quotes and the minus):

```
{searchTerms} Path:{Site} -ContentType="My Content Type Name"
```

Or use the content type ID (replace the ID with your own):

```
{searchTerms} Path:{Site} -ContentTypeId=0x0101006090CA8B789FE54589E1936EEC912F6E01
```

If the content types are children you can exclude the content with a wildcard as well.

```
{searchTerms} Path:{Site} -ContentTypeId=0x0101006090CA8B789FE54589E1936EEC912F6E*
```